# Rails 3 - submit form using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to submit my form to controller using ajax and display ajax response in my view. The form submits using ajax but I'm unable to get to 'ajax:success' or 'ajax:error' methods in my javascript. Below is a code snippet for it:

form.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for @item, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' },:id => 'item_form', :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :item_title%>
    </div>
   </div>


   <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil%>
   </div>
<% end %>

<%= javascript_tag do%>
jQuery(function($) {
alert ("load")
 $('#item_form')
 .bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status) {alert ("success")})
 .bind('ajax:complete', function(xhr, status) {alert ("complete")})
 .bind('ajax:error', function(xhr, data, status) {alert ("error")})
});
<%end%>
```

controller

```
def update
@item = Item.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
   format.html { 
      if request.xhr?
        puts "its an ajax req"
        render :json => {
            :location => url_for(:controller => 'items', :action => 'edit'),
        }

      end
   }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end

end
```

end

Comment: I also notice that my form submits twice when I do an ajax submit. I saw few posts which asked to delete public/assets, clear cache and then try again. I tried this as well but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the id you are supplying is not in the correct subhash within the options. The id would have to be inside the html options like so:

```
 <%= form_for @item, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', :id => 'item_form' }, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

Without the html id on the form, your events are not being bound.

Documentation reference:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: @user193545: I mimic'd your exact code in a new app with an item scaffold. After fixing the id, I successfully received both the success and complete events. I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.8. Here are the steps I followed:

1) rails new stackoverflow-test
2) rails g scaffold item item_title:string
3) rake db:migrate
4) rm public/index.html
5) <<copied your code into _form.html.erb & items_controller.rb>>

Let me know if there is anything else I can do to help.